# Which OS to select when writing to SD Card using PiBakery from Ubuntu

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, ubuntu

1. I installed an image of **Raspbian** on my SD Card from here [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-desktop/)
2. After that I built and installed **PiBakery** for Ubuntu as described [here](https://github.com/davidferguson/pibakery).
3. I followed [PiBakery Documentation](http://www.pibakery.org/docs/create.html) to create a setup
4. Now after creating a setup I'm struggling to write it to the SD Card as when I press "Write" I see a dialog asking to provide the operation system(but it's not mentioned in the **PiBakery Documentation**):

[image]

If I just click `Write` then nothing happens. If I try to open a folder with my `iso` file then it's not visible.

Should I find an image with another extension? Is it not possible to write a setup to an SD card with an existing OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer my own questions:

> Should I find an image with another extension?

No, what I have is completely enough.

> Is it not possible to write a setup to an SD card with an existing OS?

It's fully possible. Instead of using `Write` pick `Update`. It will push the setup to the SD Card that already contains the installed OS.

So, in my case, after I pushed the setup, put the SD card into Raspberry PI and powered it on I was able to use it successfully with all the pushed changes.